# updating user detail and role returns error

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

[image]this is the error i am getting
***The instance of entity type 'ApplicationUser' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'Id'} is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached. Consider using 'DbContextOptionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging' to see the conflicting key values***

```
public class ApplicationUser: IdentityUser
   {
       [Display(Name = "First name")]
       [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "First name required")]
       public string Firstname { get; set; }

       public string? MiddleName { get; set; }
       [Display(Name = "Last name")]
       [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "Last name required")]
       public string? LastName { get; set; }
       public string? Address { get; set; }
       
       [Display(Name = "Polling unit name")]
       [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "Polling unit name required")]
       
       public int Punit_id { get; set; }
       
       [NotMapped]
       public string? Punit { get; set; }

       [NotMapped]
       public string? RoleId { get; set; }
       [NotMapped]
       public string? Role { get; set; }
       [NotMapped]
       public IEnumerable<SelectListItem>? RoleList { get; set; }
       public bool Status { get; set; }
       public string? Gender { get; set; }
       public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
   }


[HttpGet]
public async Task <IActionResult> Edit(string userId)
       {
           var users = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(userId);

           if (users == null)
           {
              ViewBag.ErrorMessage = $"User with Id = {userId} cannot be found";
              return View("NotFound");
           }

           var model = new ApplicationUser
           {
              Id = users.Id,
               UserName = users.UserName,
               Firstname = users.Firstname,
              Middlename = users.MiddleName,
               Email = users.Email,
              PhoneNumber = users.PhoneNumber,
               Address = users.Address,
              Punit_id = users.Punit_id,
               Status = users.Status
           };
           var user = _dbContext.AppUser.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Id == userId);
           if (user == null)
           {
               return NotFound();
           }
            var userRole = _dbContext.UserRoles.ToList();
           var roles = _dbContext.Roles.ToList();
           var role = userRole.FirstOrDefault(u => u.UserId == user.Id);
           if (role != null)
           {
               user.RoleId = roles.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Id == role.RoleId).Id;
           }
           user.RoleList = _dbContext.Roles.Select(u => new SelectListItem
           {
               Text = u.Name,
               Value = u.Id
           });
             return View(user);
}

[HttpPost]
       [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
       public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(ApplicationUser users)
       {
               var users = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(user.Id);

                   if (users == null)
                   {
                       ViewBag.ErrorMessage = $"User with Id = {users.Id} cannot be found";
                       return View("NotFound");
                   }
                   else
                   {
                       users.Email = model.Email;
                       users.UserName = model.UserName;
                       users.Firstname = model.Firstname;
                       users.LastName = model.LastName;
                       users.MiddleName = model.MiddleName;
                       users.Address = model.Address;
                       users.PhoneNumber = model.PhoneNumber;
                       users.Punit_id = model.Punit_id;
                       users.Status = model.Status;
                   }


                   var userDbValue = _dbContext.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Id == user.Id);
                   if (userDbValue != null)
                   {
                       await _userManager.UpdateAsync(user);
                       //return NotFound();
                   }
              var userRole = _dbContext.UserRoles.FirstOrDefault(u => u.UserId ==userDbValue.Id);
                   if (userRole != null)
                   {
                       var previousRoleName = _dbContext.Roles.Where(u => u.Id == 
                       userRole.RoleId).Select(e => e.Name).FirstOrDefault();
                       await _userManager.RemoveFromRoleAsync(userDbValue, previousRoleName);

                   }
                  
                   
                 await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(userDbValue,_dbContext.Roles.AsNoTracking()
                .FirstOrDefault(u => u.Id == user.RoleId).Name);
                   _dbContext.SaveChanges();
                   await _userManager.UpdateAsync(users);

                   return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
               }


               user.RoleList = _dbContext.Roles.Select(u => new 
                Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering.SelectListItem
               {
                   Text = u.Name,
                   Value = u.Id
               });
               return View(user);
           }
           catch (Exception ex)
           {

               TempData["ErrorMessage"] = ex.Message;
               return View();
           }
       }
```

Comment: On what line are you receiving the error?

Comment: on my catch exception message

Comment: Hi @Obasegun, Pls share which line of your code makes such issue.